# How to get order id dynamically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

This is my code but it gives me error on line 1, **$order is not defined.**

```
<?php

   $orderId = $order->getCustomerId();

   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 

   $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository')->get($orderId); 

   //Fetch customer information

   echo $order->getCustomerEmail();
```

Comment: can you please share whole code.

Comment: this is whole code in this custom file i have created to get customer email

Comment: when i pass static id its give my result but its not take dynamic id

Comment: That why he is asking about your whole code....we need what you trying to use to get orders dynamically

Comment: Please explain in detail. Which type of dynamic order id?

Comment: your code is okay, but please identify order id... - $order is not found that's why its getting error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Create an after_order_place observer and pest below code in observer :**

```
namespace Company\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Address\CollectionFactory;

class OrderSuccess implements ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @var OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
    )
    {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {

        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

try with below code :

```
<?php

   $orderId = 1;

   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 

   $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository')->get($orderId); 

   //Fetch customer information

   echo $order->getCustomerEmail();
?>
```

Comment: its work for only order id 1  but i want when order take place then email generate and its show my current order id details not only for order 1.

Comment: you mean when place order than you get dynamic order id right ?

Comment: yes you are right when place order than i get dynamic order id